# Confluence: best way to add public restrictions of a page

Tags: confluence, restrictions

Currently we have a user guide sitting in Confluence. We want to give access to this page to all users of the product. What is the best way to do this?

Do I put the user guide into its one space and make it public. Then would I need to make a group defining all my users on our product?

It would be ideal if the users did not have to log into confluence in order to view the user guide. The most important piece is we do not want to give access to the user guide to everyone to view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grant access to the users of that product, you need to create a group, and then, give access to only that group. If users don't need to log into Confluence, then, anyone could access.

Another approach is to use [Comala Share It](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.keinoby.confluence.plugins.share-attachments/server/overview) (disclaimer, I work in Comalatech). This add-on allows you to create a unique URL, which could be shared with the users of your product, so only them could access. Of course, if the URL is shared with anyone outside the group, that person could access too. Guess the public URL is not possible, since it uses a secure token.

Regards,
Gorka